# Web Api 2 [FromBody] Request Body On Post is NULL

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, frombodyattribute

All,

First, I know similar question has been asked umpteen times. 
Second, I don't have 50 points (?!) to comment on any of them. 
Third, I cannot use "Answer" to clarify my question on those posts - I get warning I will be banned from answering any question in future.

Hence forced to ask again. I've tried all possible encodings - all 5 of them but I always get a NULL for the string Post Body for my controller below. I am using Swagger to test.

```
public class AmcoController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Amco?name=Blah
    public Amco Get(string name)
    {
        return Amco(name);
    }

    // POST: api/Amco
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Request Body --> " + value);
    }

    // PUT: api/Amco?name=Blah
    public void Patch(string name, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Amco?name=Blah
    public void Delete(String name)
    {
    }
}
```

Get works fine. Not sure what's going on. Appreciate if someone can copy/paste and test and tell me. Using VS 2017

Comment: "using Swagger to test" - do you mean Swagger UI? If yes, how does the request look like in Swagger UI? Please post a screenshot of UI, and the raw request data from the Network tab of the browser dev tools. Also, which version of Swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: What does the raw request look like? We'll need to see that in order to assess further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why swagger dosen't take a single string value from body, bu you can do the following workaround:

[image]

Change your code to accept your Amco object (I think this is also the usual case for a post request).

After this, the swagger ui should look like this and the request works fine.

[image]

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Yes, I used an instance of a class as parameter to the methods and it works. Thanks!